# Partition csv data to parquet through Glue Visual Editor, all data types getting converting to string only. but Double, Float, Long, etc Not working

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, apache-spark, parquet, amazon-athena

I am trying to Partition csv data to parquet through AWS Glue -(Visual Editor), so all data types getting converted into string only. Double,Int,Float,Long, etc Not working properly. so i am not perform SQL like operation on that data because is all type of data is string only.

- Data is stored properly in s3 -CSV format
- when data store in parquet all data is have only string type.

So what will be the reason for that ??

But my expectation is result will be store in proper format and with proper datatype. so i can perform SQL like operation on that data using AWS Athena-crawler.